# MongoDB $text operator not working in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In the last years I stumbled across a lot of bugs but this one is having me very confused. I tried finding the solution over and over but I can't find what's wrong.

I have a MongoDB database and a NodeJS server that I use to query the database. I'm currently trying to make a search API endpoint using $text. I created a text index using mongosh and everything works fine. My search query which is the following works perfectly fine in mongosh:

```
db.activities.find({ $text: { $search: 'museum' } }).limit(5)
```

So I naturally tried to implement this in my NodeJS code and I wrote this:

```
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  serverApi: {
    version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
    strict: true,
    deprecationErrors: true,
  },
});

try {
  await client.connect();
  const database = client.db("favel-test");
  const activitiesCollection = database.collection("activities");

  const activities = await activitiesCollection
    .find({ $text: { $search: "museum" } })
    .limit(5)
    .toArray();
  res.json(activities);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error occurred during MongoDB query:", error);
  res
    .status(500)
    .json({ error: "An error occurred during the query execution." });
} finally {
  await client.close();
}
```

But then I got this error:

```
Error occurred during MongoDB query: MongoServerError: error processing query: ns=favel-test.activities limit=5Tree: TEXT : query=musee, language=english, caseSensitive=0, diacriticSensitive=0, tag=NULL
Sort: { mainScore: -1 }
Proj: {}
 planner returned error :: caused by :: need exactly one text index for $text query
    at Connection.onMessage (/Users/dorian/Documents/Work/Favel/favel-api-v2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:202:26)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/Users/dorian/Documents/Work/Favel/favel-api-v2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:61:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:511:28)
    at processIncomingData (/Users/dorian/Documents/Work/Favel/favel-api-v2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:124:16)
    at MessageStream._write (/Users/dorian/Documents/Work/Favel/favel-api-v2/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:33:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:399:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:340:10)
    at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:344:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:774:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:511:28) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 291,
  codeName: 'NoQueryExecutionPlans',
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: new Timestamp({ t: 1686696409, i: 10 }),
    signature: {
      hash: Binary.createFromBase64("A9Ve+C8NJ0e92TFmw8SXCRA8cps=", 0),
      keyId: new Long("7185945864957853715")
    }
  },
  operationTime: new Timestamp({ t: 1686696409, i: 10 }),
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

As far as I understand this error suggests there is not exactly one text index in my collection but I checked multiple times and there is in fact only one text index. I am very confused and I ran out of ideas as to what may cause this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if you turn off `strict` API version?

Comment: @user20042973 Oh my god it was right there! It worked, thanks! I feel a little dumb because I never thought about checking this, but at least it works now haha

Comment: Unfortunate error message. Also doesn't seem to be covered in the docs very clearly if at all

Comment: Had a simila error - text index was created, query did work in Compass. Same connection string -- error in NodeJS. The only difference was the strict option. Removed it - the query now works!